# Vue component Data not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component

I have a Vue Component which I reuse on the same page. I use a bootstrap 4 modal in the component. My problem is when I update the component data in the bootstrap modal, the data bind is not working properly when I reuse the same component in the view page.

Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="pageContent">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button @click="filterHistory">Add</button>
            <button @click="closeFilter">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Headline -->
    <h1>{{filter}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: "Table",
  data() {
    return {
      filter: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterHistory() {
      this.filter = true
    },
    closeFilter() {
      this.filter = false
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

And here I reuse it in a view page:

```
<template>
  <div id="userInfo" v-bind:class="myval.theme">
     <Test></Test>
     <Test></Test>
  </div>
</template>
```

The value of filter, which is a boolean expression, is only updated in the component declared first. So the data binding fails... Has anyone come across this? Or know how to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you want the data variable of both the `Test` component to be updated?

Comment: I want to use the test component twice. But when I do, the {{filter}} data variable is only updated in the first declared test component.

Comment: Each component has its own context. If you want to share the context, then you might want to have the data variable in the parent component and update via emitting event from the child component.

Comment: `id="test"` Both of your modal instances will have the same ID, which will probably cause issues. You might want to look into generating a unique ID for each instance of your component.

Comment: Thank you @Hiws! Binding an id as a prop from the parrent component solved the issue!